# Reloading python module when its loaded via "from pymod import *"

Tags: python

Suppose I import several functions from a python module in the following way:

```
import module1
from module2 import *
```

Now, if I change one of the functions in the module1, I can just run

```
reload(module1)
```

But I can't do the same for module2
How can I do the same for reloading all the functions in module2?  Currently, I have to exit and restart iPython.

I am using Python 2.7.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

best advice is to not use `from module2 import *`.... if you don't want to retype `module2` each time, you could do something like `import module2 as m2`

then you can `reload(m2)`